# how to make segmentation mask given region marked with dotted line in python

Tags: python, xml, opencv, image-segmentation

I want to make segmentation masks for some images by coding. There is a tool that can generate xml file with coordinates of boundary points approximately. These coordinates can be obtained by getting tag values. The image size is 800x600 pixels.

For example, following points are extracted from this tool. How can I fill the region inside the contour marked with the dotted lines with e.g. white colour? Thanks.

points = [(737, 255), (736, 265), (735, 270), (739, 273), (746, 264), 
    (755, 268), (765, 272), (767, 276), (769, 278), (776, 275), (776, 264), 
    (767, 260), (753, 257), (738, 256), (738, 256), (479, 247), (455, 244), 
    (446, 245), (440, 243), (430, 244), (423, 241), (419, 238), (412, 232), 
    (406, 225), (403, 202), (404, 185), (410, 170), (414, 166), (424, 160), 
    (439, 157), (456, 166), (469, 177), (472, 197), (480, 199), (492, 214), 
    (494, 207), (488, 201), (492, 193), (497, 194), (502, 196), (510, 196), 
    (518, 197), (523, 202), (521, 209)]

```
import Image
import numpy as np

a = Image.new('RGB',(800,600),0)
for p in points:
  a.putpixel(p,(255,255,255))
a.show()
a.save('./Original_mask.png')
```

Original_mask:
[image]

Expected_mask:
[image]

Comment: @thewaywewere Where are the images?

Comment: Oh, the images weren't uploaded. Added back now.

Comment: Ok,  then I want to see the original xml file. I think the there must be some label info in the xml. Other wise, why do you make sure there are two regions, not just only one?

Comment: I do not have the xml file at home. Actually there were several more regions in this mask based on the coordinates I extracted. For simplicity I removed some of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a tag called 'object' in the xml file, so instead directly read attribute of points I should have first found all objects, then drawn the contour defined by each object.

Answer (score 2):

Basically speaking, if you want to fill region limited by scattered points, you can use `cv2.drawContours`.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

points = [
    (737, 255), (736, 265), (735, 270), (739, 273), (746, 264),
    (755, 268), (765, 272), (767, 276), (769, 278), (776, 275), (776, 264),
    (767, 260), (753, 257), (738, 256), (738, 256), (479, 247), (455, 244),
    (446, 245), (440, 243), (430, 244), (423, 241), (419, 238), (412, 232),
    (406, 225), (403, 202), (404, 185), (410, 170), (414, 166), (424, 160),
    (439, 157), (456, 166), (469, 177), (472, 197), (480, 199), (492, 214),
    (494, 207), (488, 201), (492, 193), (497, 194), (502, 196), (510, 196),
    (518, 197), (523, 202), (521, 209)
    ]

canvas = np.zeros((600, 800,3), np.uint8)
pts = np.array([[x,y] for(x,y) in points])
cv2.drawContours(canvas, [pts],-1, (0,255,0), -1)
cv2.polylines(canvas, [pts], isClosed=True, color=(255,0,0), thickness=2)
cv2.imshow("canvas", canvas);cv2.waitKey();cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image]

---

I think the order of the points maybe wrong.